# Pattern for ASP.NET MVC View Hide/Unhide Controls

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a POEAA

I have a standard ASP.NET MVC View with tons of input controls. The visibility of the controls is triggered based on inputs from 2 main dropdown controls. for e.g. DropDown1 with value A and DropDown2 with value B will show only few controls from the full list and will also change the mandatory requirements.

How should I design the view?

1. Write java script and hide/unhide based on the DropDown combinations.There can be 30 combinations so might be challenging to manage on new controls and combinations
2. Create a table in database that will give a list of control ids for each combination and then on client side loop through it to hide/unhide?
3. Any other patterns someone can suggest? Aim is to keep it clean and manageable

**Real World Example**

Working on a property listing form. Based on the selected property type and transction type, the controls are hidden/shown.

For e.g. Bedrooms and Bathrooms do not apply to a Plot/Land. There are 2 dozen such controls whose visibility needs to be managed based on the property type/transaction type comibination.

The list can grow...

Thanks,
Pinakin

Comment: How about, redesign your system so that you don't have this problem? Anytime that the coding gets really hard is a good indication that you've approached it incorrectly.

Comment: +1 just to balance the downvotes - I don't think it's a bad question.

Comment: Thanks Lazarus. I am still designing the system. Trying to find good patterns to deal with this kind of situations. I am not sure why it is termed a HOMEWORK question.

Comment: @Lazarus How is that comment constructive? The question **is about** how to approach the problem.

Comment: @Pinakin Shah Could you describe what the purpose of the form is, on a high level? For example, what do the dropdown lists represent? What happens when the user submits the form? Etc.

Comment: @Anders Fjeldstad Its a property listing form. Based on the selected property type and transction type, the controls are hidden/shown. For e.g. Bedrooms and Bathrooms do not apply to a Plot/Land. There are 2 dozen controls whose visibility needs to be managed and the list can grow.

Comment: @Pinakin Shah So it's basically a search form? Will the model use the same logic for retrieving properties regardless of the input? Or does the controller parse the parameters and then redirect to the proper search method (e.g. GetPlots(...), GetHouses(...), GetAppartments(...))?

Comment: @Anders Sorry with property listing I meant, adding a new property. Same thing applies for searching properties. Havent

Comment: @AndersFjeldstad let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1149/discussion-between-pinakin-shah-and-anders-fjeldstad)

Comment: @Anders Fjeldstad : Simply providing an answer does nothing to help the OP in understanding the problem space. My comment was intended to cause the OP to think about the problem space and look to different ways they might approach this problem and future problems using the rule that when it starts to look hard then another approach is probably more appropriate. This isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A system. The OP is looking for discussion and encouraging it isn't in keeping with the system goals.

Comment: @Lazarus I agree, I just don't think your first comment was very helpful (i.e. "Q: How should I approach this problem design-wise? A: Redesign your system."). That being said, the answer you wrote later is a good one and the general principle of reevaluating the current design when things become cumbersome of course is very valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest looking at a more reactive approach by implementing the MVVM pattern and would suggest looking at [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) as a method of binding your model to your controls and their attributes such that changing your model will have effects beyond the value being changed.

Hopefully this will give you some ideas on how to move forward but I stand by my original comment, look to re-evaluate how you are presenting the user interface. 30 controls on a single view is too much. Break it down into smaller chunks, if it's tough for you to manage then it's tough on the user too.

Comment: all 30 controls are not visible at a time. the combination triggers the visibility.

Comment: I realise that you want to selectively show and hide the controls but from your description all 30 are present on in the view and that's too many. Any time you see many options that need to be completed, try looking for a path through them that would allow you to present subsets of the options in logical groups so that the user can complete the subset and move onto the next, the next group being selected based on the previous set of responses. It's a classic "Wizard" approach.

Comment: agree completely. The view is just a subset of the total information needed to make a single property entry. There is a map selection, picture upload, client information etc. I am planning to use a Wizard approach to make it easy for the user. Might split the basic information too into wizard steps.

Comment: Exactly, that's the thought process I was hoping you would get to when I first commented. A core skill for a developer is being able to look at a complex problem and break it down into manageable chunks both for themselves (so it's easier to code) and for the user (so that it's easier to use). We all have limited capacity for the number of things we can keep in mind simultaneously, the smaller the number of items for your focus, the easier it is and the more focus each gets. There are limits obviously but it's always a good starting point.

Comment: I had the Wizard in mind but only for the top level split. Basic Info, Map, Pictures, Client etc. I think splitting the basic info further will add more clicks and round trips. The basic question still remains of hiding/unhiding the controls whatever approach we take.

Comment: But a much smaller group of controls with each wizard page, so breaking the problem down in to smaller, more manageable chunks.

Comment: Agree. will try to put all the suggestions together for a appropriate solution

Comment: checked the knockoujs and its awesome. I have done WPF MVVM and could directly see the value. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a web based app you should be looking to decompose any complex input screens into the least complex views as possible, primarily from the users point of view.

For example, rather than modify one monolithic options page, have the drop down combinations direct the browser to a page/view that is specific for that combination.

You will end up with a number of specific pages/views, but you are left with a number of advantages:

1. User is not presented with a
   radically changing web page that may
   confuse them
2. A less complex page results in a lower
   chance for problems due to a partial
   page load
3. Your pages/views are encapsulated: You
   know any changes will affect only
   that combo

Repetition can be minimised through the use of includes/user-controls and common code blocks to keep your code as DRY as possible.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the property type and transaction type as action method parameters, and then displaying different views based on these? You could then have the resulting form post back to different actions depending on the context, which would make validation easy. I think that's an approach that is pretty maintainable. (Of course, you could still add UX improvements such as loading the view via AJAX instead of full redirects.)

You could have a common base class for the view models for the different scenarios and use the `EditorForModel` helper to display the proper form for each derived type.

```
public abstract class PropertyViewModelBase { ... }
public class ApartmentForRentViewModel : PropertyViewModelBase { ... }
public class LandForSaleViewModel : PropertyViewModelBase { ... }
```

Then in your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddProperty(int propertyType, int transactionType) 
{
    PropertyViewModelBase viewModel = // Perhaps a factory that returns an
                                      // empty instance of the proper type?

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Somewhere in the (strongly typed) view:

```
@model MyApp.Models.PropertyViewModelBase

[...]

@Html.EditorForModel()
```

And you'll have to define an editor template (partial view) for each deriving type of `PropertyViewModel`. If you would like to have the form posted to different action methods depending on property type + transaction type, include the entire HTML form in the editor template.

That's *one* possible approach, with the benefit of turning a monolithic, gigantic form into several smaller, more specialized ones.